# Mapproxy tms config reveals no layers

Tags: tile-map-service, mapproxy

I have configured MapProxy to reveal a wms service and tms service. Problem is, the tms don't show anything. (WMS works excellent)

Opening the demopage I cannot se any layers (as one can do in for example [ORKa.MV](https://www.orka-mv.de/geodienste/orkamv/demo/))

I have preseeded the cache at C:\Pythonenv\mapproxy\cache\topo_color\sjobo_ruta\0\0\0.png and the file is there and looks good but when trying to access the seeded tile through http://127.0.0.1:8081/tms/1.0.0/topo_color/sjobo_ruta/0/0/0.png gives me a 404 error.

What am I missing?

```
globals:
  srs:
    axis_order_ne: ['EPSG:3008']
  cache:
    base_dir: C:\\Pythonenv\\mapproxy\\cache
    lock_dir: C:\\Pythonenv\\mapproxy\\cache\\locks
    tile_lock_dir: C:\\Pythonenv\\mapproxy\\cache\\tile_locks
    meta_size: [2, 2]
    meta_buffer: 80

services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    origin: 'nw'
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:3008']
    versions: ['1.1.1', '1.3.0']
    image_formats: ['image/png']

sources:
  lm_wms1:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: http://user:password@maps.lantmateriet.se/topowebb/wms/v1?
      layers: topowebbkartan
    coverage:
      bbox: [149981, 6152974, 181706, 6184699]
      srs: 'EPSG:3008'

layers:
  - name: topowebbkartan
    title: Lantmateriet Topowebb - www.lm.se
    sources: [lm_wms1]

caches:
  topo_color:
    grids: [sjobo_ruta]
    sources: [lm_wms1]
    cache:
      type: file
      directory_layout: tms
      use_grid_names: true

grids:
  sjobo_ruta:
    srs: EPSG:3008
    bbox: [149981, 6152974, 181706, 6184699]
    bbox_srs: EPSG:3008
    origin: nw
    tile_size: [1024, 1024]
    res: [
        64.0000000000,
        32.0000000000,
        16.0000000000,
         8.0000000000,
         4.0000000000,
         2.0000000000,
         1.0000000000,
         0.5000000000,
         0.2500000000,
         0.1250000000,
   ]
```

I use MapProxy 1.12.0 with Python 3 and GDAL on Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I forgot to add the cached tiles to the layers list. The above configuration holds another error in the grid section as I have set the origin to nw rather than sw.